# Is there a simpler way to create a symbolic link to a file in the current directory than by typing out the complete filepath?

Tags: symlink

I know that [when creating symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux#1951752) the paths must be absolute, or [relative to the destination location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951742/how-to-symlink-a-file-in-linux#comment73185439_1951752)

If I'm making a link in `/usr/local/bin` that points to a file in the current directory, is there an easier way - something, for example, that works with tab-completion in bash - than to do ...

```
ln -s $(pwd)/target_file /usr/local/bin/
```

...?
(Where `$(_something_)` evaluates the `_something_` and substitutes it into the shell command.)

Comment: `ln -s $PWD/<tab>` works for me.

Comment: Well, I guess using the shell variable is better than using substitution. Thanks for the info. (Why not make it an answer?)

Comment: Wasn't sure if it worked for you.

Comment: Indeed it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tab-completion for files works with the `$PWD` variable for me:

```
bash-4.4$ touch bar baz
bash-4.4$ ln -s $PWD/ba<tab>
bar  baz
```

Answer (score 2):

For completion, some alternatives in `zsh`:

- `~0` (or `~+0`) is a slightly shorter alternative for `$PWD` (and filename completion works just as well after `$PWD/fi<Tab>` than after `~0/fi<Tab>`, or `$(pwd)fi<Tab>`); `~1`, `~2`... are the previous directories you've been in, the completion system can also be configured to show you which they were and be expanded (upon `~+<Tab>`).
- One can use `ln -s file(:A) /usr/local/bin`, where `(:A)` causes `file` to be expanded to its absolute path (beware that it resolves symlinks to their targets though).

Also note the `-r`/`--relative` option of GNU `ln`:

```
ln -rs file /usr/local/bin/
```

Would make a `/usr/local/bin/file` symlink that points (as a relative path, so maybe something like `../../../home/you/file`) to the `file` in the current directory, similar to:

```
ln -s "$(realpath -s --relative-to=/usr/local/bin file)" /usr/local/bin
```

(with GNU `realpath`).